# Issue with tar during webrtc fetch inside Docker ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, webrtc, github-actions, tar

I'm trying to build webrtc using github actions with Docker Ubuntu container. And receiving bunch of `tar: ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.67.1: Cannot change ownership to uid 376730, gid 89939: Invalid argument` like messages while webrtc fetch process. I'm found possible solution with `--no-same-owner` tar parameter but can't figure out how to force tar to use it on every .tar file which webrtc fetch want to process.

Workflow:

```
name: Build

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        include:
          - os: Linux
            container: ghcr.io/<company>/<name>
      ...        
    name: ${{matrix.os}}, ${{matrix.arch}}    
    runs-on: [ "self-hosted", ...]
    container: ${{ matrix.container }}
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build WebRTC
        if: ${{matrix.os == 'Linux'}}
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git depot_tools
          export PATH=$(pwd)/depot_tools:$PATH
          mkdir webrtc_build
          cd webrtc_build
          fetch --nohooks webrtc && gclient sync
    ...
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo clang build-essential cmake git libssl-dev curl python3 && \
    ...
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Docker publish workflow:

```
on:   
  ...
jobs:
  push:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, ...]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag <name> --label "runnumber=${GITHUB_RUN_ID}"

  ....     

      - name: Push image
        run: |
          docker tag <name> ghcr.io/<company>/<name>
          docker push ghcr.io/<company>/<name>
```

Comment: Please include your minimal working workflow in your question to reproduce this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Did you try building it without container?

Comment: @Azeem. Yes, it works fine. But unfortunally, I have to use container

Comment: Right. That is the custom Dockerfile that you're using? Where is it being used in your workflow?

Comment: @Azeem, there is another workflow, which publish docker image to the github. And I use it by the link in the `container` section of the main workflow. I added it to the main question as well

Comment: Got it. Did you try adding `USER root` in Dockerfile?

Comment: @Azeem, its root already. `id` gives `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: Right. By default, it should be unless specified otherwise. I was wondering about `uid 376730, gid 89939` and thought maybe it's related to that.

Comment: @Azeem, I think it's related to that... I tried to create and set user in Docker file, but it leads to errors after gh actions workflow start. I tried to set user in the `Build WebRTC` step as well (`su user` which proceeds no errors), but `id` still gives `uid=0(root)...`.  On the other hand I downloaded this image to my laptop, run it,  changed user and it works locally.

Comment: So, setting the user manually is working fine?

Comment: Also, see [`jobs.<job_id>.container.options`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontaineroptions) and [`--user / -u`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#options).

Comment: @Azeem, "So, setting the user manually is working fine?" - I mean it works only locally. Generally webrtc fetch works fine locally as well. But it doesn't works for gh actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding environment variable `TAR_OPTIONS`:

```
    env:
      TAR_OPTIONS: --no-same-owner
```